# Would canvas based charts be seen by Google as duplicate images?

Tags: seo, svg, canvas, charts

Until March/April this year, I had used images sourced from Google Images - ie duplicate images. As a result, my performance on Google was awful. For over 10, long, very long years...!

Now that I've removed the images my rank is improving (albeit excruciatingly slowly). My question is whether I should add example charts onto my pages - because charts look the same (or similar) no matter where you see them (ie whichever site that you see them on), and being canvas/SVG-based Google would probably look at them as images. Presumably, it would then classify them as similar to images on other sites (because charts do tend to look alike).

On the other hand, other sites have charts plastered all over them and seem to do well in the SERPs (certainly a whole lot better than me!).

Do you see the conundrum here? (no countdown jokes please...)

There used to be a chart on practically every documentation page - now they're few and far between.

Comment: Charts are difficult to interpret by search engines, but they will probably try. You can help a lot by adding a good description of the canvas. For instance [inside the canvas tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453899/seo-for-content-inside-canvas-element), or in the same section as the canvas. Good original content, which users are interested in, will always win the SEO battle.

Comment: What about SVG then - presumably this wouldn't be such an issue as SVG can be "indexed" by Google...?